# How to show html response in windows gadget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

[Please Click this my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pWFX.png)    Sample.Html
    -------------

```
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Unicode" />
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/My.js"></script>
<script src="https://jspm.io/system@0.16.js"></script>
<script type="text/jscript" language="jscript">

$("#gadgetContent").ready(function(){
    LoadData();
});

</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
   <body id="gadgetContent">
       <table>
          <tr> 
             <td>
                 <span id="span1"></span>
             </td>
          </tr>
       </table>
   </body>
</html>

My.js
------




function LoadData() {
   System.Gadget;


     document.body.style.width=150;
     document.body.style.height=150;
     document.body.style.margin=0;
     document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";

     document.getElementById("gadgetContent").style.color = 'white';

   var MemoryText="";
   MemoryText = document.getElementById("gadgetContent");
        console.log(MemoryText);
    ajaxcall();  
  }
 function ajaxcall(){
     var url = "http://localhost/MemorySpace.svc/MemoryData";
     console.log(url);
     $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8;",
        url:url,        
    crossDomain : true,
       dataType: "json",
        success:function(data){ 

            var trHtml=data.GC1;
               $("#span1").html(trHtml);
        },
        error:function(data){
          console.log(data.responseText);
        }
     });
 }
```

Hi, Am Create own Gadget get Server memory using WCF service.

Add Code and attched image file

working fine. i am get in result browser level but didn't get output from Windows Gadget Level

I try to more than way didn't get result please give the solution

[OUTPUT:Browser and Gadget Lavel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0YYJ.png)

Comment: Hi,Please any one give the solution?

Comment: Hi,Please any one give the solution?

Comment: Did you got any solution for this?

Comment: @AjuJohn No,you have any solution?

Comment: I made it work by not using jquery. Use plain Javascript. Then it is working fine.

Comment: Please give me code..